# Image interpolation with Javascript or WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, interpolation, webassembly

I have a picture that I draw pixel by pixel on the canvas. Size of the image: 512 * 256. When I make this picture 1536 * 768, the image looks very bad. I think I can use interpolation to fix this. But I couldn't find a good javascript library. It didn't work in the libraries I found.

My code is as follows. I find the color equivalent according to the values and reflect that color on the screen.

```
function ImageData(ctx, points) {

    var data = ctx.createImageData(512, 256);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 4)
    {
        var colorIndex = GetColorCode(points[i/4], minColorIndex, maxColorIndex);
        var color = colormap[colorIndex];

        data.data[i+0] = color[0];
        data.data[i+1] = color[1];
        data.data[i+2] = color[2];
        data.data[i+3] = 255;
    }

    return data;
}

function Draw (points)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = ImageData(ctx, points);

    ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: What the code is for and exactly what problem you want to solve the code above? And how this code do with WebAssembly?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to resample an ImageData is to put it at its real size and then draw the target canvas over itself, rescaled, simply by using `drawImage`.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
// prepare our 50*50 ImageData
const data = new Uint32Array( 50 * 50 );
crypto.getRandomValues( data ); // make some noise
const imgData = new ImageData( new Uint8ClampedArray( data.buffer ), 50, 50 );
// put it on canvas @scale(1)
ctx.putImageData( imgData, 0, 0 );
// at this step, our canvas only contains this 50*50 ImageData

// resize using the default interpolation

// we first change the composite mode to be able to clear while drawing
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
ctx.scale( 10, 10 ); // so 500x500
// newest browsers can control interpolation quality
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";
ctx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );

// clean
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

And to avoid interpolation (closest neighbor), then do the same, but set `imageSmoothingEnabled` to false:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

const data = new Uint32Array( 50 * 50 );
crypto.getRandomValues( data ); // make some noise
const imgData = new ImageData( new Uint8ClampedArray( data.buffer ), 50, 50 );

ctx.putImageData( imgData, 0, 0 );

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
ctx.scale( 10, 10 ); // so 500x500

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );

// clean
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: The image I plotted is like the second code snippet. I have to use a gradient or interpolation (or any other way??) to get an unblurred image.

Is there any way I can do this?